# Getting Error :The absolute uri: http://displaytag.sf.net cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-1

I am new to struts. Currently I am using Struts 1.3 in our application.

I am getting the following error:

```
"The absolute uri: http://displaytag.sf.net cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application"
```

Do I need to make entry in web.xml and i am deploying my code in Tomcat 7.

This is my Jsp Code

```
<%@ include file="common-includeCMTT.jsp"%>
<%@ page import="java.text.DateFormat" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.text.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./compo.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/sortable-tables.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabs-2.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<title>View the Logged Maintenance</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Enter-listener
if (document.layers)
  document.captureEvents(Event.KEYDOWN);
  document.onkeydown = function (evt) { 
      var keyCode = evt ? (evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode) : event.keyCode;

      if (keyCode == 13)   //13 = the code for pressing ENTER
      {
        if(!valForm('<%= CMTEvent.SEARCH_EVENT %>'))
        {
         return false;
        }
      }
    }

  function valForm(evt) {
        //alert(evt);
        var form = document.MaintenanceForm;
        var refno = form.MRN.value;
        var cirid = form.circuit_id.value;
        var usid = form.usid.value;
        var routername = form.router_name.value;
        var customercode = form.customer_code.value;
        var carrierreference = form.carrier_reference.value;
        var circuitstatus= form.circuit_status_id.value;
        var equantcircuitid = form.equant_circuit_id.value;

        if(refno =="" && cirid == "" && usid == " " && routername == "" && customercode == "" && carrierreference == "" && circuitstatus == "" && equantcircuitid == "")
        {
            alert("Please enter any one of the field to proceed with search");
            return false;
        }       
        else
        {
        quickSearch('MRN', form.MRN.value, 'circuit_id',form.circuit_id.value, 'usid',form.usid.value,'router_name',form.router_name.value,'customer_code',form.customer_code.value,'carrier_reference',form.carrier_reference.value,'circuit_status_id',form.circuit_status_id.value,'equant_circuit_id',form.equant_circuit_id.value);
        }

    }
</script>

</head>
<body class="COMPO">
<!-- Wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- Container -->
<div id="container" class="resolution">
<!-- Colonnage -->
<div id="colonnes" class="clear">
<!-- Right column -->
<div>
<!-- Page title -->
<br/>
<h2 class="title_n1_orange"><%=bundle.getString("cmttS.title") %></h2>
<!-- tabpanel_maintenance_data -->
<div id="tabpanel-demo" class="tab_panel_2 clear">
<ul id="tabpanel-liste" class="tab_menu clear">
<li class="tabpanel-tabbar-item tab_active"><a href="#content01" class="tabpanel-tabbar-link">Search</a></li>
<li class="tabpanel-tabbar-item"><a href="#content02" class="tabpanel-tabbar-link">Maintenance Details</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- Tab_content 01- Search Page -->
<div id="content01" class="tab_panel_content_2">
<div class="form">  
<html:form method="POST" action="searchMaintenance">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="Search Maintenance Page" class="tables">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th scope="row"><label for="circuit_id"><%=bundle.getString("searchM.CircuitId") %></label></th>
<td><input type="text" name="circuit_id" id="circuit_id" class="field_size_e"/> </td>
<th scope="row"><label for="usid_id"><%=bundle.getString("searchM.Usid") %></label></th>
<td><input type="text" name="usid" id="usid_id" class="field_size_e" readonly="readonly"/> </td>
<th scope="row"><label for="router_name_id"><%=bundle.getString("searchM.RouterName") %></label></th>
<td><input type="text" name="router_name" id="router_name_id" class="field_size_e" readonly="readonly"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row"><label for="customer_code_id"><%=bundle.getString("searchM.CustomerCode") %></label></th>
<td><input type="text" name="customer_code" id="customer_code_id" class="field_size_e"/> </td>
<th scope="row"><label for="MRN_ID"><%=bundle.getString("searchM.MRN") %></label></th>
<td><input type="text" name="MRN" id="MRN_ID" class="field_size_e" value=" "/> </td>
<th scope="row"><label for="carrier_reference_id"><%=bundle.getString("searchM.CarrierReference") %></label></th>
<td><input type="text" name="carrier_reference" id="carrier_reference_id" class="field_size_e"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row"><label for="circuit_status_id"><%=bundle.getString("searchM.CircuitStatus") %></label></th>
<td>
<select id="circuit_status_id" name="circuit_status_id" class="field_size_e">
<option value="">-<%=bundle.getString("common.select")%>-</option>
<option value="1">NO CSM</option>
<option value="2">CIRCUIT CEASED</option>
<option value="3">IMR RAISED</option>
<option value="4">NO</option>
</select>

</td>
<th scope="row"><label for="Eq_Circuit_ID"><%=bundle.getString("searchM.ECId") %></label></th>
<td><input type="text" name="equant_circuit_id" id="Eq_Circuit_ID" class="field_size_e" readonly="readonly"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>    
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>         

<td><button type="submit" class="button_action_standard" onclick="javascript:valForm('<%= CMTEvent.SEARCH_EVENT %>');"><span>Search</span></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="reset" class="button_action_standard" onclick="submitEvent('RESET_EVENT');"><span>Reset</span></button></td>
<!-- <td><button type="reset" class="button_action_standard"><span>Reset</span></button></td> -->
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</html:form> 
</div>  

<display:table export="true"  id="data" name=""  requestURI="/searchMaintenance.do" pagesize="5" >
            <display:column property="maintenanceReferenceNumber" title="Reference" sortable="true"   />
            <display:column property="wfStatus" title="WfStatus" sortable="true"  />
            <display:column property="circuitStatus" title="Circuit Status" sortable="true"  />
            <display:column property="wfDate" title="WfDate" sortable="true"  />
            <display:column property="country" title="Country" sortable="true"  />
            <display:column property="city" title="City" sortable="true"  />
            <display:column property="carrierName" title="Carrier Name" sortable="true"  />
            <display:column property="circuitId" title="Circuit Id" sortable="true"  />
            <display:column property="startDate" title="Start Date" sortable="true"  />
            <display:column property="time" title="Time" sortable="true"  />
            <display:column property="duration" title="Duration" sortable="true"  />
            <display:column property="impact" title="Impact" sortable="true"  />
</display:table>

</div>
<!-- /Tab_content 01- Search Page-->
</div>
<!-- / tabpanel_maintenance_data-->
 </div>
 <!-- /Right Column -->
</div>
<!-- /Colonnage -->
</div>
<!-- /Container -->
</div>
<!-- /Wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Could anyone guide me on this. Please suggest me Struts 1.3 tutorials and sample examples

Thanks

Comment: Do you have display-tag library in your classpath? I mean is it available in `WEB-INF/lib` folder?

Comment: If you're new, why not [Struts2](http://struts.apache.org/) - struts1 is officially retired.

Comment: Sorry to mention Its part of build-path.

Comment: CUrrently my project build on struts 1.3 so need to use that

Comment: Can anyone suggest me on this